# How can you use TLS for Kafka in Quarkus?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, quarkus

The [Kafka guide from Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka) works nicely when running Kafka locally in Docker. I'm trying to change this sample by replacing the local Kafka service with a hosted Kafka service in the cloud which requires TLS.

Does anyone know how I can configure this? In the [Quarkus documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config) and the [Smallrye documentation](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/#_interacting_with_apache_kafka) I don't see any properties for this.

I'd like to use the Kafka service in the IBM Cloud. Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/EventStreams?topic=eventstreams-kafka_using#kafka_api_client) I've tried the following configuration in application.properties:

```
kafka.bootstrap.servers=broker-0-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-4-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-3-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-5-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-2-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-1-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093
kafka.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="token" password="...";
kafka.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
kafka.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
kafka.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
```

Update:
I've also tried Gunnar's suggestion below, but it doesn't work. When I use the following application.properties ...

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.topic=prices
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer

mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="token" password="...";
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2

mp.messaging.incoming.prices.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.topic=prices
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer

mp.messaging.outgoing.prices.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="token" password="...";
mp.messaging.outgoing.prices.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
mp.messaging.outgoing.prices.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
mp.messaging.outgoing.prices.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2

kafka.bootstrap.servers=broker-0-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-4-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-3-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-5-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-2-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093,broker-1-8c8cph49mx2p2wqy.kafka.svc01.us-south.eventstreams.cloud.ibm.com:9093
```

... I get an error:
javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid channel configuration - the `connector` attribute must be set for channel `prices`
at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle.onApplicationStart(SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle.java:22)

Is TLS currently possible for Kafka in Quarkus?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the relevant properties at the channel level? E.g.

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.topic=mytopic
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.ssl.protocol=...
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.ssl.keystore.location=...
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.ssl.keystore.password=...
```

You also could refer to variables when requiring the same values for multiple topics.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gunnar. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Now it complains about a missing connector attribute, even though I haven't touched that one. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You are mixing `incoming` and `outgoing` for the `prices` channel. It should be either one.

Comment: Aaah. Copy and paste error. It works now! Thanks a lot, Gunnar!

Comment: @Gunnar, I have a similar issue where Im trying to connect my quarkus application with kafka producer to a broker secured using keycloak. I have the "auth-server-url", "realm", "client-id" and "client_secret", but unable to get this working. Hope you could throw some light on this as I could not find the corresponding application properties reference.

Answer (score 0):

One property is incorrect in the accepted answer by @Gunnar. It should be "security" instead of "ssl" in the property name.

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.security.protocol=SSL
```